# Group by Count of DateTime Per Hour by removing Duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named loginData:

```
userName timestamp
abc      '2007-01-01 12:00:12 AM'
def      '2021-01-01 12:09:12 AM'
abc      '2021-01-01 12:40:12 AM'
abcde    '2021-01-01 12:44:12 AM'
```

From this table I want to query the data in such a way that It doesn't count duplicates. I want to get data like this:

```
userLoggedIN - 3
```

Considering `abc` has logged in twice to count it as one. How to do this?

Comment: You're expected to do some research and have a go before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct userName)
from loginData;
```